# Bitbucket pipelines webpack build and ftp deploy NO JS OUTPUT on the server

Tags: git, webpack, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have my pipelines build settings:

```
  branches:
    production:
    - step:
        name: Build and test JS.
        image: node:8.9.3
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - npm run-script build
    - step:
        name: Build and test PHP.
        image: php:7-fpm
        script:
          - echo "Here will be the Composer build and PHPUnit tests."  
    - step:
        name: Deploy to FTP.
        image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
```

...and the problem is that it build without errors but then there is no standard webpack output js file on my server (that should appear after `npm build` that runs webpack). How can I "put" that output js file to my server on that build? Please for help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already found a solution since the last 6 months... If anyone had the same trouble : here is what i found.

Bitbucket Pipelines doesn't save the build that Webpack (^4.12.0) produces when the mode is set as "production". Everything is working perfectly when the build is in a development mode (or "none" mode).

```
export default {

/*=========================================
=            JAVASCRIPT FILES            =
=========================================*/

// https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

target: 'web',

// production, development, none

mode : 'none',
```